# What are the methods of tagging commits for a release on GitHub?

Tags: github

What are the ways to Tag commits on GitHub - the only ways I've seen is to create a Release, which targets a branch and tags all the commits on that branch. Or via the terminal which you can tag commits individually - `git tag -a v1.2 9fceb02`

Is there an easier way to bulk tag a lot of commits on a particular branch (e.g. `master`) but not all of the commits?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easier way to bulk tag a lot of commits on a particular branch (e.g. master) but not all of the commits?

Well, no, considering a tag only reference *one* commit, so your "bulk tag" operation would need to somehow increment its naming convention.

Since a release (IE. *one* release) only needs *one* tag, the simple way is a

```
git tag -m "my release" v1.0.0 <acommitID>
git push --tags
```

That is enough to create a tag on top of which you can create one release.